# Calling Me.Validate on a Windows Form does not fire the Validating event in VB.NET, how can I make it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, validation

I would like to use the built-in Validation framework in my VB.NET Windows Forms application.

In a form I need to validate a specific control in the form. This I can easily obtain by manually calling `ValidateChildren()` when needed. However I ***also*** need to do a **form wide validation** not specific to any control.

I tried to do this by calling `Me.Validate()` (for the form) and handle the `Me.Validating` event. However when calling `Me.Validate()` the **event is not fired** for some reason.

I have `CauseValidation = True` set for the form and all controls.

How can I obtain what I want using the built-in validation framework?

Comment: is this what you try to achieve? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558621/why-is-my-validating-event-not-firing-in-c

Comment: No, I know how to validate the children, but I need to fire some custom not control related code when i call the form.validate procedure (which should fire the form.validating event).

Comment: I just experienced exactly the same behavior and would also be very interested in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that the behavior described in the question is **by design**.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf8t2at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (highlights by me):

> ### ContainerControl.Validate Method ()
>
> (..)
>
> #### Remarks
>
> The Validate method validates **the last child control that is not validated** and its ancestors up through, but ***not including, the current container control***.